# Why does this DateTime.Parse() call throw in .NET 4 but not .NET 2?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I have a small application that behaves differently in .NET 2.0 and 4.0.

Did something change with regards to `DateTime.Parse()` between .NET 2 and .NET 4?  The following snippet behaves differently on each.

```
// when targeted for .NET 2.0, this prints out: 21/03/2012...,
// which is correct presentation for my regional settings
//
// however, when compiled for .NET 4.0, this throws a FormatException
// {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}

var it = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-It");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("21-mar-2012", it));
```

EDIT:

I'm doing some scrubbing on a code-base for these types of problems.  I'm trying to induce failures but I was surprised to find my test-app (.NET 4) throw, but the actual app (.NET 2) work fine.

Comment: Which FormatException is thrown?  There's three possible reasons to throw FormatException with DateTime.Parse.  If you provide more of the detail of the FormatException, someone might be able to give you an answer.

Comment: {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}

Comment: I don't think that date format was ever valid.  I find it odd that it worked in .net 2, as it's not defined anywhere as a valid format.

Comment: Some things get re-written from version to version, possibly part of the re-write improved error checking or validation...